# Draggable HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the user to be able to move a HTML element around inside another by dragging with the mouse.
(Example, move the red square inside the yellow square)

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:yellow">
<div style="width:10px;height:10px;background-color:red">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is some support for drag and drop in HTML5, but I think to get what you want, you'd have to add in a JavaScript framework.  Something like Draggable in jQuery UI (https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) comes to mind.  Is that okay?

Comment: I'll be using JS, though I'd like to keep the code relatively short. I won't be able to use jQuery though.

Comment: found this jsfiddle link. pure JS draggable example.  https://jsfiddle.net/tovic/Xcb8d/

Comment: @BobPickle Cool.  If the answer I've added below solves your question, feel free to click the checkmark to accept.  If it doesn't quite do that, just let me know and I can revise.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using a simple and popular library called [Draggabilly](https://github.com/desandro/draggabilly) which doesn't require jQuery.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var draggie = new Draggabilly('.draggable', {
    containment: true
  });
};
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.draggable {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Based on the Draggabilly containment example using jQuery - http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/azRmYv -->

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/draggabilly@2.1/dist/draggabilly.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="draggable"></div>
</div>
```

Note: Should you decide to use jQuery, the JavaScript could be simplified:

```
$(function(){
  $('.draggable').draggabilly({
    containment: true
  });
});
```